# Woocommerce No Recent Orders Text

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have woocommerce set up and working correctly, I am just in need of a little tweak.

On the my-account page the default is recent orders, which shows the recent orders a customer has made. But if there are no orders the page is blank. 
I would like to add a line of text to show that the page is loaded and maybe encourage the user to create an order.

Where would I add this in to the my-orders or my-accounts pages to show only when there are no others orders present? Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would copy the `my-orders.php` template into your theme (At `wp-content/themes/my-theme/woocommerce/myaccount/my-orders.php`).

You will see that this template has an if statement:

```
if ( $customer_orders ) : 
// prints the orders table
endif;
```

You would only need to give this statement an `else` condition like so:

```
if ( $customer_orders ) : 
// prints the orders table
else :
  echo 'please buy some stuff';
endif;
```